# sending json to view but appears like a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, razor

How can i return json data to a razor view.

at the moment i can send it something like this:

i am assigning it to a hidden field:

```
"[{"title":"aa","description":"bb"},{"title":"cc","description":"dd"},{"title":"ee","description":"ff"}]"
```

but it just appears as a string when i do:

```
var places = $('#hidden-places').val();
```

how do i make it so that places is not like a string? but an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [`.parseJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) function:

```
var places = $.parseJSON($('#hidden-places').val());
alert(places[0].title); // should alert 'aa'
```